# JacksonXmlRootElement with dynamic localName value

Tags: java, xml, jackson, pojo, xmlmapper

I am updating a `POJO` that we map to `XML` and the only difference is that someone wants both the old `XML` and some new, and with the only difference being the root Wrapper name (all the same fields), e.g. currently the root Xml Tag is set to `ExistingName` and they want a new value like `BrandNewName` with all the same fields. And still get the old. Is there a way to just flip this in the `POJO`?

I figured I could do it with some inheritance and a base class with two implementations, but seemed overkill

I know I can set the root tag with `@JacksonXmlRootElement`, but is it possible to set it to a variable name.

```java
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = 'ExistingName')
class MyPojo {
    String commonVar1
    String commonVar1
    String commonVar1
}
```

Comment: Root element name in `XML` during deserialisation should not be a problem. `<ExistingName>...</ExistingName>` - will be deserialised and `<MyPojo>...</MyPojo>` will be properly deserialised. What problem do you have with old `XML` files?

Comment: There is no problem with the old xml. It is valid and they still want it.

They just also want in other situations the same xml, with a different root name. 

So, are you saying
1) Deserialize with it is as
2) Replace `ExistingName` w/ `BrandNewName`?

Comment: So, you want to serialise the same `POJO` as two different root elements, am I right? Do you use one global `ObjectMapper` configuration or you use many local instances?

Comment: ```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper()
String xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(save)
```

Note, I was able to do it by making a parent class with all the fields and extending to two child classes, that simply have different `@JacksonXmlRootElement`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up finding [Get Jackson XMLMapper to set root element name in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070531/get-jackson-xmlmapper-to-set-root-element-name-in-code) and just setting using

```
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
.writer()
.withRootName(myFieldName)
.writeValueAsString(myPojo ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MixIn` feature and dynamically declare name for root type:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;

public class XmlMapperApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XmlMapper xmlMapperOld = new XmlMapper();
        xmlMapperOld.addMixIn(MyPojo.class, MyPojoExistingNameMinIn.class);

        XmlMapper xmlMapperNew = new XmlMapper();
        xmlMapperNew.addMixIn(MyPojo.class, MyPojoBranNewNameMinIn.class);

        System.out.println(xmlMapperOld.writeValueAsString(new MyPojo()));
        System.out.println(xmlMapperNew.writeValueAsString(new MyPojo()));
    }
}

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "ExistingName")
interface MyPojoExistingNameMinIn {
}

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "BrandNewName")
interface MyPojoBranNewNameMinIn {
}
```

Above code prints:

```
<ExistingName><commonVar1>Var1</commonVar1><commonVar2>Var2</commonVar2><commonVar3>Var3</commonVar3></ExistingName>
<BrandNewName><commonVar1>Var1</commonVar1><commonVar2>Var2</commonVar2><commonVar3>Var3</commonVar3></BrandNewName>
```

But we can also create an extra `POJO` to store object and name we want to assign during serialisation process. To make it work we need to implement custom `JsonSerializer` and implement that behaviour. Example solution could look like below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.NameTransformer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.ser.ToXmlGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.ser.XmlBeanSerializer;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;

public class XmlMapperApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        for (char c = 65; c < 70; c++) {
            System.out.println(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(new PersistAs("ExistingName_" + c, new MyPojo())));
        }
    }
}

class PersistAsJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<PersistAs> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(PersistAs value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        ToXmlGenerator xmlGen = (ToXmlGenerator) gen;
        // set desired name
        xmlGen.setNextName(new QName(value.getName()));
        xmlGen.writeStartObject();

        // serialise fields
        XmlBeanSerializer serializer = (XmlBeanSerializer) serializers.findValueSerializer(value.getValue().getClass());
        JsonSerializer<Object> unwrappingSerializer = serializer.unwrappingSerializer(NameTransformer.NOP);
        unwrappingSerializer.serialize(value.getValue(), gen, serializers);

        // end of root
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}

@JsonSerialize(using = PersistAsJsonSerializer.class)
class PersistAs {
    private final String name;
    private final Object value;

    public PersistAs(String name, Object value) {
        this.name = Objects.requireNonNull(name);
        this.value = Objects.requireNonNull(value);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PersistAs{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", value=" + value +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
<ExistingName_A><commonVar1>Var1</commonVar1><commonVar2>Var2</commonVar2><commonVar3>Var3</commonVar3></ExistingName_A>
<ExistingName_B><commonVar1>Var1</commonVar1><commonVar2>Var2</commonVar2><commonVar3>Var3</commonVar3></ExistingName_B>
<ExistingName_C><commonVar1>Var1</commonVar1><commonVar2>Var2</commonVar2><commonVar3>Var3</commonVar3></ExistingName_C>
<ExistingName_D><commonVar1>Var1</commonVar1><commonVar2>Var2</commonVar2><commonVar3>Var3</commonVar3></ExistingName_D>
<ExistingName_E><commonVar1>Var1</commonVar1><commonVar2>Var2</commonVar2><commonVar3>Var3</commonVar3></ExistingName_E>
```