# @JacksonXmlRootElement use multiple localname to match 2 identical xml file with only different root name

Tags: xml, jackson, xml-deserialization

I want to parse xml to java object two identical xml with the only root tag name different:

```
<root1>
    <a></a>
    <b></b>
    <c></c>
</root1>
```

```
<root2>
    <a></a>
    <b></b>
    <c></c>
</root2>
```

It is possible to do it using only one pojo annotated with something like

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "root1|root2") ?

Comment: did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

With the inspiration/idea from [JacksonXmlRootElement with dynamic localName value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58382190/jacksonxmlrootelement-with-dynamic-localname-value), I used the interface based solution.

I declared the main (data) class `Root`, which I did not annotate with `@JacksonXmlRootElement`. Then declared two interfaces, `Root1` and `Root2` with both `@JacksonXmlRootElement` and made `Root` to implement them both.

The solution in Kotlin would be:

```kotlin
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "root1")
interface Root1

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "root2")
interface Root2

data class Root(
    @field:JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "a") val a: String,
    @field:JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "b") val b: String,
    @field:JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "c") val c: String
): Root1, Root2
```